# 半角カナをWebページで使用することについて

Tags: 文字化け

**半角カナを、Webページで使用しない方が良いですか？**
・UTF-8でページ作成しても関係ない？
・下記で言うところのブラウザは、かなり古いブラウザのことですか？

---

> 半角カタカナを使用するとブラウザ上で文字化けをおこす可能性があります

[総務省](http://www.soumu.go.jp/soutsu/tokai/siensaku/accessibility/L3_text1.html)

> 文字化けを起こす可能性のある丸付き数字、ローマ数字など機種依存文字や半角カタカナについては使用を禁止します

[内閣府](https://www.cao.go.jp/notice/webaccessibility.html)

Comment: どちらのリンク先にも「古い」ブラウザという話は出てこないので、質問文とつながらない気がします。

Comment: アップデートされていない資料は自らを「古い」と主張しません。

Comment: 解決済みのようですが、何のために?　　半角カナ、全角英数字は、互換のためで、推奨するものでは無かったと思います。もし、文字の大きさなどの問題でしたら、フォント依存でサイズは保証されません。単なるデザインの問題でしたら、やめて欲しいと思う。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WHATWGの勧告によると、HTMLで使用する文字コードはUTF-8でなくてはならない（must）ようです。

- [Encoding Standard](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#names-and-labels)
- [HTML Standard 日本語訳](https://momdo.github.io/html/semantics.html#charset) : 同記事日本語訳

ここで、半角カナはUTF-8でサポートされている文字であるため、使っても問題ありません。

Answer (score 1):

引用されている資料にある「文字化け」と「機種依存文字」の2つは似て非なる問題なのですが、PicoSushiさんの回答にあるとおりUTF-8を使えばどちらも解消されるため、半角カナを使っても全く問題ありません。

> 下記で言うところのブラウザは、かなり古いブラウザのことですか？

というご質問については、どちらかというとこれらの問題は**古いブラウザで起こる**というよりは**古い常識・考え方に基づいている記述**です。昔は、（Unicodeが登場する以前の話はここではしませんが）ブラウザがちゃんとUTF-8に対応していても、ウェブページを製作する側がちゃんと文字化け対策をできていないために文字化けが発生する場合が多々ありました。それに対する場当たり的な対処の一環として「半角カナを避ける」といった対策があったと考えられます（メールでの文字化けの問題もあり、それに引きずられていた面もあったでしょう）。

特に昔はテキストエディタのデフォルトエンコーディングがUTF-8でない場合があり、文字コードに関するリテラシーが低いウェブ制作者がUTF-8以外のエンコーディングでページを作ったり、あるいはウェブページのエンコーディング指定を正しく行なわなかったりして文字化けを発生させていました。

今はUTF-8の勢力が非常に強くUTF-8以外のテキストデータが扱われることが少なくなっていますから、このような文字化けの問題は自然消滅に向かっています。

Answer (score 1):

昔々、ブラウザにページのエンコーディングを伝える手段が無かったり限られていた時代がありました。ブラウザはエンコーディングの指定がなければ自動判定をしていましたが、半角カナが含まれている Shift_JIS は EUC-JP に誤判定されやすいという問題がありました。そのため、半角カナを避けるのがベストプラクティスでした。

現在はエンコーディングをちゃんと指定すれば半角カナの表示は問題ないと思われます。
(しかし、よほどの理由がない限りは使うものでもないと思います)

Comment: 日本限定かもしれませんがデカアスキーアート（テキストアートというほうが良いらしいですが）では半角カナもガンガン使っていますので、 Web 系エンジニアが思っているよりは半角カナが使われている機会は多いと思います。